# Acceder a valores constantes desde el html con Angular

Tags: angular, angular8

Actualmente tengo una aplicación hecha con angular 8
y tengo definido un listado de contantes para los nombres de los botones de la siguiente forma

```js
export const Botones = {
    okCrear: 'Crear',
    okActualizar: 'Actualizar',
    okEnviar: 'Terminar',
    cancelar: 'Cancelar',
    regresar: 'Regresar',
    limpiar: 'Limpiar campos'
};
```

Actualmente accedo a dichas contantes refiriéndolas desde el .ts de la siguiente forma:

```js
import { Componentes, Iconos, Botones, IconosBotones } from 'src/app/_constantes/ui.constants';

export class MyComponente {
  componentes = Componentes;
  iconos = Iconos;
  botones = Botones;
  iconosBotones = IconosBotones;
}
```

y desde el html las accedo así:

```html
<div class="form-action-buttons">
                <button type="button" color="accent" mat-raised-button (click)="navegarLista()">
                <mat-icon>{{iconosBotones.regresar}}</mat-icon> {{botones.regresar}}
                </button>
                <button type="button" type="button" color="warn" mat-raised-button (click)="limpiarFormulario()">
                    <mat-icon>{{iconosBotones.limpiar}}</mat-icon> {{botones.limpiar}}
                </button>
                <button color="primary" mat-raised-button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">
                    <mat-icon>{{iconosBotones.okEnviar}}</mat-icon> {{botones.okEnviar}}
                </button>
            </div>
```

lo que quiero saber es si desde el html existe alguna forma de acceder directamente el valor de las constantes sin tener que referirlas desde el ts previamente

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te paso esta sencilla explicacion de por que no puedes hacer lo que quieres.

Traduccion:

> En Angular2, la plantilla (html) solo puede acceder a los campos y
>   métodos de la clase componente. Cualquier cosa mas esta fuera de sus
>   limites. Esto incluye cosas que son visibles a la clase componente.
>
> La manera de sortear esto es tener un campo dentro del componente, que
>   haga referencia solo a la constante, y usar esa.
>
> Es una limitación del diseno, pero mas importante deberías pensar mas
>   acerca de por que necesitas constantes en la plantilla en primer
>   lugar. Normalmente estas cosas son usadas por los componentes en si, o
>   los servicios, pero no las plantillas.

---

Puedes encontrar la repuesta original en ingles aqui[aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40237663/4326551).

Comment: Gracias Angel muy claro